# Rephrasing the use of a user defined function in an oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a user defined oracle function which is used in the following way.

```
 select
        table1.id,
        table2.id,
        ..
 from
        table1, table2
 where
        func(table1.id) = table2.id;
```

We can ignore other fields of both tables.

Now, func(x) basically queries table1 for a different field (id1) corresponding to the argument given.

func(x) can be defined as

```
   select 
          id1
   from
          table1
   where
          table1.flag = 'Y'
          and id = x;

   if id1 is null, func(x) returns x else it returns id1.
```

Given that it is known the query is invoked millions of times, how can i rephrase the function in order to improve the efficiency of the operation performed?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the logic without the function would be:

```
 select table1.id, table2.id, ...
 from table1, table2
 where table1.id = table2.id and table1.flag = 'y' and table1.id1 is null or
       table1.id1 = table2.id and table1.flag = 'y'
```

This might best be implemented as a `union` or `union all`:

```
 select table1.id, table2.id, ...
 from table1 join
      table2
      on table1.id = table2.id and table1.flag = 'y' and table1.id1 is null
 union
 select table1.id, table2.id, ...
 from table1 join
      table2
      on table1.id1 = table2.id and table1.flag = 'y';
```

A function call in the `where` clause is not going to optimize very well.  Even an `or` statement often impedes optimization.  The `union` can result in better performing subqueries, which makes up for the increased computation for removing distinct values.